# Is it possible to display a print preview on a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

To clarify I have a macro which applies formatting to a excel range based on user selections, after a selection has been made I'm curious to see if a print preview of the changes made can be displayed on that same userform the selections were made. If so can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not without some ActiveX control that can render it, no.

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").PrintPreview
End Sub
```